# How to set Sqlite3 to be case insensitive when string comparing?

Tags: sqlite, case-insensitive

I want to select records from sqlite3 database by string matching. But if I use '=' in the where clause, I found that sqlite3 is case sensitive. Can anyone tell me how to use string comparing case-insensitive?

Answer (score 604, accepted):

You can use `COLLATE NOCASE` in your `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE name = 'someone' COLLATE NOCASE
```

Additionaly, in SQLite, you can indicate that a column should be case insensitive when you create the table by specifying `collate nocase` in the column definition (the other options are `binary` (the default) and `rtrim`; see [here](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation)).  You can specify `collate nocase` when you create an index as well.  For example:

```
create table Test
(
  Text_Value  text collate nocase
);

insert into Test values ('A');
insert into Test values ('b');
insert into Test values ('C');

create index Test_Text_Value_Index
  on Test (Text_Value collate nocase);
```

Expressions involving `Test.Text_Value` should now be case insensitive.  For  example:

```
sqlite> select Text_Value from Test where Text_Value = 'B';
Text_Value      
----------------
b               

sqlite> select Text_Value from Test order by Text_Value;
Text_Value      
----------------
A               
b               
C    

sqlite> select Text_Value from Test order by Text_Value desc;
Text_Value      
----------------
C               
b               
A
```

The optimiser can also potentially make use of the index for case-insensitive searching and matching on the column.  You can check this using the `explain` SQL command, e.g.:

```
sqlite> explain select Text_Value from Test where Text_Value = 'b';
addr              opcode          p1          p2          p3                               
----------------  --------------  ----------  ----------  ---------------------------------
0                 Goto            0           16                                           
1                 Integer         0           0                                            
2                 OpenRead        1           3           keyinfo(1,NOCASE)                
3                 SetNumColumns   1           2                                            
4                 String8         0           0           b                                
5                 IsNull          -1          14                                           
6                 MakeRecord      1           0           a                                
7                 MemStore        0           0                                            
8                 MoveGe          1           14                                           
9                 MemLoad         0           0                                            
10                IdxGE           1           14          +                                
11                Column          1           0                                            
12                Callback        1           0                                            
13                Next            1           9                                            
14                Close           1           0                                            
15                Halt            0           0                                            
16                Transaction     0           0                                            
17                VerifyCookie    0           4                                            
18                Goto            0           1                                            
19                Noop            0           0
```

Comment: After (re)creating the table with 'COLLATE NOCASE', I noticed it was _much_ faster than the query WHERE name = 'someone' COLLATE NOCASE.  
MUCH faster (six to 10 times, roughly?)

Comment: According to the documentation, adding `COLLATE NOCASE` to the index is not required if the field itself already has this collation defined: "[*The default collating sequence is the collating sequence defined for that column in the CREATE TABLE statement.*](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html)"

Comment: `COLLATE NOCASE` will only work with ASCII text. Once you have "FIANCÉ" or "voilà" in your column values, it won't match against "fiancé" or "VOILA". After enabling the ICU extension, [`LIKE` becomes case-insensitive](http://www.sqlite.org/src/artifact?ci=trunk&filename=ext/icu/README.txt), so `'FIANCÉ' LIKE 'fiancé'` is true, but `'VOILA' LIKE 'voilà'` is still false. And ICU+LIKE has the drawback on not using the index, so it can be slow on big tables.

Comment: select  div,case when div = 'fail' then 'FAIL' else 'PASSED' end,* from marks collate nocase above didnt work am I doing some thing wrong?

Comment: @Mytskine Did you manage to solve 'VOILA' LIKE 'voilà' with ICU?

Comment: To perform diacritics-insensitive LIKE you shall tweak ICU extension so <code>VOILA LIKE voilà</code>  becomes TRUE. Just call this function http://stackoverflow.com/a/13071166/110076 to remove diacritics from icuLikeCompare() function of ICU extension.

Comment: @DefenestrationDay When you say you (re)created the table, do you mean you were able to update the existing one, or you actually dropped the existing one and created a new one altogether?

Comment: One thing to note that tripped me up: `select * from tbl where firstname='john' and lastname='doe' COLLATE NOCASE` will be case insensitive on `lastname`. To be case insensitive on `firstname`, write this: `select * from tbl where firstname='john' COLLATE NOCASE and lastname='doe'`. It's specific to that one column, not the entire `where` clause.

Answer (score 153):

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE name = 'someone' COLLATE NOCASE
```

Comment: If you are like me and want more documentation on Collating, you can find it here on this page :http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Just scroll down to #6.0

Comment: @will: It's now point #7 and directly accessible with https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collating_sequences

Answer (score 60):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE name LIKE 'someone'
```

(It's not *the* solution, but in some cases is very convenient)

[LIKE operator](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like)

> "The **LIKE** operator does a pattern
> matching comparison. The operand to
> the right contains the pattern, the
> left hand operand contains the string
> to match against the pattern. A
> percent symbol ("%") in the pattern
> matches any sequence of zero or more
> characters in the string. An
> underscore ("_") in the pattern
> matches any single character in the
> string. **Any other character matches**
> **itself or its lower/upper case**
> **equivalent (i.e. case-insensitive**
> **matching)**. (A bug: SQLite only
> understands upper/lower case for ASCII
> characters. The LIKE operator is case
> sensitive for unicode characters that
> are beyond the ASCII range. For
> example, the expression 'a' LIKE 'A'
> is TRUE but 'æ' LIKE 'Æ' is FALSE.)."

Comment: @MM-BB yes, unless we perform the LIKE on a column which is declared (or indexed) as COLLATE NOCASE, it will do a full scan of the rows.

Comment: It is not a bug, it is a documented limitation. The same page quoted in the answer mentions the ICU extension that manages unicode characters. (Perhaps it wasn't the case in 2009)

Comment: This will produce unexpected results if your search contains `%`

Comment: @StevenPenny, yes, of course. The "LIKE" operator does a pattern matching comparison, which is mentioned in my answer.

Comment: The  docs for `LIKE` are [here](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like)

Comment: There is also a performance impact when using the like operator. This impact will become noticeable as the number of queries increases.

Answer (score 47):

This is not specific to sqlite but you can just do

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE UPPER(name) = UPPER('someone')
```

Comment: The other part of the performance concern is finding the matching rows in the table.  Does SQLite3 support function-based indexes?  Indexing the search column or expression (e.g. "UPPER(name)") in a situation like this is usually a good idea.

Comment: Watch out with this one, as cheduardo hinted, SQLite cannot make use of an index on 'name' when running this query. The db engine will need to full-scan all rows, converting all of the 'name' fields to upper case and running the comparison.

Comment: This is ASCII only - something like `Jóga` will fail

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to create your own custom collation. You can then set that collation on the column or add it to your select clauses. It will be used for ordering and comparisons.

This can be used to make 'VOILA' LIKE 'voilà'.

http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_create_collation

> The collating function must return an integer that is negative, zero, or positive if the first string is less than, equal to, or greater than the second, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

Another option that may or may not make sense in your case, is to actually have a separate column with pre-lowerscored values of your existing column. This can be populated using the SQLite function `LOWER()`, and you can then perform matching on this column instead.

Obviously, it adds redundancy and a potential for inconsistency, but if your data is static it might be a suitable option.

Answer (score 0):

If the column is of type `char` then you need to append the value you are querying with spaces, please refer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314052/sqlite-query-case-sensitive/16314153) . This in addition to using `COLLATE NOCASE` or one of the other solutions (upper(), etc).

Answer (score -1):

use like this

```
 "select * from $pwsXDataHistory where type = '$type' COLLATE NOCASE and $t_uStatus != '$DELETE' order by $t_name COLLATE NOCASE asc ");
```