# Sort results from an Android sdk Cursor's managedQuery in a case insensitive manner

Tags: android, sql, sorting, cursor, mediastore

I'm using the string 'MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC"' to sort the resultant list of a managedQuery in an Android Cursor but, unfortunately, my items that begin with 'a' appear after the items that begin with 'Z'...  I would like to know how to perform a managedQuery with the resultant list sorted in a case-insensitive fashion.  Help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick google search turns up this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188749/how-to-change-the-collation-of-sqlite3-database-to-sort-case-insensitively) which almost directly answers your question. But since I'm assuming you'll want to retain the case of the strings for when you actually need to access the file, you can just use the COLLATE command when your selecting. You'll want a query that looks like this:

```
select file_name_column from table_name where file_name_column like "%.mp3" or file_name_column like "%.wav" ORDER BY file_name_column COLLATE NOCASE ASC;
```

Comment: 'MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC"'   worked.... thanks!!!!  You're the best!  =-D