# How to apply own sorting logic for elements display in ListView?

Tags: android, sorting, android-sqlite, comparable, android-cursor

I use standard approach to display my database records in the ListView:

```
recordsCursor = mDb.query(DATABASE_BL_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_BL_ROWID, KEY_BL_SENDER, KEY_BL_ADDED}, null, null, null, null, KEY_BL_SENDER);
startManagingCursor(recordsCursor);

String[] from = new String[]{DbAdapter.KEY_BL_SENDER};
int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.mylist_row, recordsCursor, from, to);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

So, all records are sorted by `KEY_BL_SENDER`. 
I would like to implement the following sorting logic:

1. ignore case (so, the list of 4 elements - `aa`, `bb`, `AA`, `BB` will be displayed in the following order: `AA`, `aa`, `BB`, `bb`);
2. ignore other symbols besides letters (the list of 4 elements - `** aa **`, `~bb~`, `aa`, `__BB__` will be displayed in the following order: `aa`, `** aa **`, `__BB__`, `~bb~`).

How could I do it?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898227/rearrange-list-view-items-in-simplecursoradapter

Comment: Thanks, @italo. I found how to ignore case - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7934364/604388. But your link doesn't help me with task 2.

Comment: "*ignore case ... capital letters ideally should be first*" - You might want to clarify that. It's contradictory right now.

Comment: Just to clarify - it shows how to implement own sorting logic, but doesn't show how to apply that to my query.

Comment: Your (1) is contradictory as you require a specific way to sort. No 2 I dont think is possible by using a SQL query, you will probably have to do that in code.

Comment: @Geobits, thanks for your comment - I've removed this statement. Actually, I wanted to say that if there are two equal values and just case is the difference, then capital letters should go first (i.e. `A`, `a` and not `a`, `A`).

Comment: Why did you edit that part out then? "Ignore case" means that capital letters *don't* necessarily go first. You should have removed the "ignore case" part if that's what you want.

Comment: @Geobits, I've removed this part since it is not so important. The most important part is to ignore case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's join some known solutions:

- [Rearrange list view items in SimpleCursorAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898227/rearrange-list-view-items-in-simplecursoradapter)
- [Sort results from an Android sdk Cursor's managedQuery in a case insensitive manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934285/sort-results-from-an-android-sdk-cursors-managedquery-in-a-case-insensitive-man/7934364#7934364)

Your query would look like:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM ... 
WHERE ... 
ORDER BY 
    TRIM(KEY_BL_SENDER, "_*~ #$") 
    COLLATE NOCASE ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks, italo. It looks really simple. Is there any approach to replace ALL characters except of letters instead of having many-many `REPLACE`s?

Comment: Hmm. Do I understand `TRIM` correctly - it will remove characters in the beginning and the end, but will not help with cases like `*a*b*c*`, `abc`,  where `REPLACE` helps? PS. Don't worry - I'll accept your answer, just would like to clarify it further ;).

Comment: Yes. You're right. Trim will take care of your 2nd requirement, but will not solve cases like a*b*c. In this last case you will need a cascate of replaces. Take a look at http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html to find more functions.