# How to determine if SQLite column created with COLLATE NOCASE

Tags: sql, sqlite

A column in a SQLite db must be COLLATE NOCASE. I assume there is no way to add that capability to an existing table, so I'm prepare to recreate the table with it. How can I determine if the existing column is COLLATE NOCASE in order to avoid recreating the table every time it is opened?

Comment: Maybe this helps:https://stackoverflow.com/q/1188749/3270427

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I determine if the existing column is COLLATE NOCASE

The query

```
SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND tbl_name='my_table'
```

will give you the `CREATE TABLE` statement for that table. You could inspect the DDL to determine if the column is already defined as `COLLATE NOCASE`.

Comment: Thanks Gord - this was the info I was looking for. I can rapidly determine if I need to change MyTable. If so, with SQLite I create a TempTable with the desired NOCASE; INSERT INTO TempTable SELECT * FROM MyTable; DROP TABLE MyTable; and finally  'ALTER TABLE TempTable RENAME TO MyTable'; Very fast :)

Answer (score 0):

You might not need to do that at all if it is sufficient to change the collations in the query. I mean you can just overwrite it in the query. It won't affect constraints or index, but depending on your use case, it might be good enough.

To be clear: the collate clause in the table definition is just a default for the queries. You can overwrite this in the queries.

e.g.

```
 WHERE column = 'term' COLLATE NOCASE
```

or

```
 ORDER BY column COLLATE NOCASE
```

However, not that SQLite's `LIKE` doesn't honor collate clause (use `pragma case_sensitive_like` instead).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most general way is store a version number somewhere (in another table, or with  [PRAGMA user_version](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_user_version)).

If you want to check the column itself, use a query with a comparison that is affected by the column's collation:

```
SELECT Col = upper(Col)
FROM (SELECT Col
      FROM MyTable
      WHERE 0       -- don't actually return any row from MyTable
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'x'    -- lowercase; same collation as Col
     );
```