# Avoid duplicate entries without being case-sensitive?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

How to avoid duplicate entries without being case-sensitive?

If somebody inputs "Blue" and "Blue" already exists in the database, I don't insert the new input to avoid duplicates.

However, if somebody inputs "BlUe", my query to check if the input already exists returns false and it is inserted.

Without apply strict formatting, ie: capitalizing the first letter of each word and lowercasing the rest, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Sqlite3 to be case insensitive when string comparing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973541/how-to-set-sqlite3-to-be-case-insensitive-when-string-comparing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `collate nocase` in your column definition

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973541/how-to-set-sqlite3-to-be-case-insensitive-when-string-comparing

Answer (score 1):

Usually this work is done from both sides: you make upper case before pass the value to the database and in sql also use TO_UPPERCASE.

Answer (score 0):

try the where clause as something like this. where `UPPER('BLUe') = UPPER(colValue)`

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would store values in the database in a single case (probably lower) and do you comparison case-insensitive.  For display you can just save the display value as the user entered it (keeping mixed case), or you can do formatting for the case you want.

Comment: i don't think you should be forced to store data in a specific case just for this purpose.  just use a select statement to UPPER each field so they appear to be the same case

Comment: @binnyb: but wouldn't that ruin indexing gains?

Comment: it kind of depends on if you need to index it or not for query performance. I like the 'collate nocase' answer to handle it better.