# How to make this Android SQLite join query

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

SQL joins have never been my strength. I would like some help with this one. It is probably an easy one for you SQL maestros.

I have 2 tables with the same columns. Let's say their structure is:

```
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
key INTEGER,
description TEXT NOT NULL,
size INTEGER,
timestamp LONG,
is_on INTEGER
```

The table names are *Shirts1* and *Shirts2*. The tables represent 2 versions of a dataset, and have a high amount of data overlap. The goal is to find which rows are different. *key* is the key which remains the same from version to version. Remaining columns can change from version 1 to 2.

Answers should be ideally for SQLite on Android. Multiple queries are OK - need not be 1 query.

My guess

```
SELECT * FROM Shirts1, Shirts2 WHERE Shirts1.key=Shirts2.key AND 
        (Shirts1.description != Shirts2.description OR 
        (Shirts1.size != Shirts2.size OR
        (Shirts1.timestamp != Shirts2.timestamp OR
        (Shirts1.is_on != Shirts2.is_on)
```

Another concern is would a query like this cause issues on an Android phone with limited device memory? There are 1000 rows in both tables. Should I break out the query into multiple queries, limiting comparison to 100 rows at at time for instance, as *key* goes from 1-1000 in order.

Comment: It should work fine but try it on actual data & check the performance on the real device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shirt1:

```
1;1;"green_shirt";1;1;1
4;4;"yellow_shirt";1;1;1
```

Shirt2:

```
1;1;"green_shirt";1;1;1
2;2;"red_shirt";1;1;1
3;3;"orange_shirt";1;1;1



SELECT shirt2.*
  FROM shirt1
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN shirt2 ON shirt1.key = shirt2.key
 WHERE shirt1.description != shirt2.description OR
       IFNULL(shirt1.size, -1) != IFNULL(shirt2.size, -1) OR
       IFNULL(shirt1.timestamp, -1) != IFNULL(shirt2.timestamp, -1) OR
       IFNULL(shirt1.is_on, -1) != IFNULL(shirt2.is_on, -1)      
 UNION ALL
SELECT shirt1.*
  FROM shirt2
 RIGHT JOIN shirt1 ON shirt1.key = shirt2.key
 WHERE shirt1.description != shirt2.description OR
       IFNULL(shirt1.size, -1) != IFNULL(shirt2.size, -1) OR
       IFNULL(shirt1.timestamp, -1) != IFNULL(shirt2.timestamp, -1) OR
       IFNULL(shirt1.is_on, -1) != IFNULL(shirt2.is_on, -1)
 UNION ALL
SELECT shirt1.*
  FROM shirt1
 INNER JOIN shirt2 ON shirt1.key = shirt2.key
 WHERE shirt1.description = shirt2.description OR
       IFNULL(shirt1.size, -1) = IFNULL(shirt2.size, -1) OR
       IFNULL(shirt1.timestamp, -1) = IFNULL(shirt2.timestamp, -1) OR
       IFNULL(shirt1.is_on, -1) = IFNULL(shirt2.is_on, -1)
```

Output:

```
2;2;"red_shirt";1;1;1
3;3;"orange_shirt";1;1;1
4;4;"yellow_shirt";1;1;1
1;1;"green_shirt";1;1;1
```

If you want to exclude the shirts that are included in shirt1/shirt2 you just have to remove the last union. That means

```
SELECT shirt2.*
  FROM shirt1
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN shirt2 ON shirt1.key = shirt2.key
 WHERE shirt1.description != shirt2.description OR
       IFNULL(shirt1.size, -1) != IFNULL(shirt2.size, -1) OR
       IFNULL(shirt1.timestamp, -1) != IFNULL(shirt2.timestamp, -1) OR
       IFNULL(shirt1.is_on, -1) != IFNULL(shirt2.is_on, -1)      
 UNION ALL
SELECT shirt1.*
  FROM shirt2
 RIGHT JOIN shirt1 ON shirt1.key = shirt2.key
 WHERE shirt1.description != shirt2.description OR
       IFNULL(shirt1.size, -1) != IFNULL(shirt2.size, -1) OR
       IFNULL(shirt1.timestamp, -1) != IFNULL(shirt2.timestamp, -1) OR
       IFNULL(shirt1.is_on, -1) != IFNULL(shirt2.is_on, -1)
```

Output:

```
2;2;"red_shirt";1;1;1
3;3;"orange_shirt";1;1;1
4;4;"yellow_shirt";1;1;1
```

Think you will want everything in the same column so I think this should be the better solution. If you are ok with having different columns for shirt1/shirt2 then you can also use select * and ignore the union.

About the device question: Depends on the device, but if the device is old then  I don't think that the query will be your main issue. You could also try to add a few indices to improve performance.

Edit: changed the solution to join on the key column

Comment: i guess integers can be null thats why the ifnull check is needed.. btw, i believe _key_ is what is we need to join on. also can you explain what you mean by "everything in the same column", please?

Comment: I mean that if you do a select * you would get something like shirt1.key, shirt2.key and so on (so you would get a column for every column in every shirt). I think you would prefer a solution where you only have one column (so for for the keys you would get a single column named key with the joined values of shirt1 and two) and have both values in that single column.

Comment: i see. btw, can you do string comparison with **!=**? or is there a function? the comparison needs to be utf8 because the description can be foreign languages.

Comment: If you don't have any special requirements like case independence it should work in this way.

Comment: how would i make it case independent?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973541/how-to-set-sqlite3-to-be-case-insensitive-when-string-comparing

Comment: For other people, the UNION shows both versions of a row that is different.

Comment: I modified my solution and added output. As I wasn't really sure what you meant I included two solutions with input/output.