# Case insensitive order by with ormlite and sqlite in android

Tags: android, ormlite

I want to order my data objects from an ORMLite DAO case insensitively.

Currently I am using the following sqlite code to order my owner items case sensitively:

```
ownerDao.queryBuilder().orderBy("Name", true).query();
```

I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973541/how-to-set-sqlite3-to-be-case-insensitive-when-string-comparing) that sqlite supports case insensitive "order by" with the following raw SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM owner ORDER BY Name COLLATE NOCASE
```

Any easy way (easier than calling `queryRaw()`) of adding the desired suffix?

Could an alternative solution be to set the `columnDefinition` property on the [DatabaseField annotation](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_2.html#SEC7) to `TEXT COLLATE NOCASE`?

Comment: have you tried `orderBy("Name COLLATE NOCASE", true)` maybe it goes through that way.

Comment: I thought about that, but even if that works, it might break with some future version of ORMLite.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think what you want is to use the [`QueryBuilder.orderByRaw(String)` method](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/QueryBuilder.html#orderByRaw%28java.lang.String%29).  It would look something like:

```
ownerDao.queryBuilder().orderByRaw("Name COLLATE NOCASE").query();
```

Notice the raw string does *not* contain the `ORDER BY` part of the string.  To quote the [javadocs](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/QueryBuilder.html#orderByRaw%28java.lang.String%29):

> Add raw SQL "ORDER BY" clause to the SQL query statement. This should not include the "ORDER BY".

The `TEXT COLLATE NOCASE` `columnDefinition` might work although I don't have any experience with using that at all.

Also, I would *not* use the `orderBy("Name COLLATE NOCASE", true)` answer since typically [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) tries to escape the column names and the quotes would be in the wrong place.

Comment: orderByRaw("Name COLLATE NOCASE") works as expected. Thanks Gray