# ORMLITE Query for french text ignoring accent on Android

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, collation, ormlite

I've been looking for how to make a request on my sqlite Database via `ORMLITE` to get result no matter what letter insensitive or not and with accent or not, (e.g. : e or é or è or E , etc...)

Does anyone can give me a hint about how I can do that. I've tried what was advised, but it ain't working at all, [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281087/case-insensitive-order-by-with-ormlite-and-sqlite-in-android/10285533#10285533) :

This question have been reported as duplicate with that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282083/how-to-ignore-accent-in-sqlite-query-android) which is not the same at all, what I want is to found a solution using the COLLATE FEATURE to avoid the creation of a third column to just host the content in ascii.

---

*I'd like to say to the people who just report this as duplicate, this is not really smart of them. You should at least post a comment or an answer which could be helpful. Instead of just reporting to a question I've read already at that moment.*