# How to create a "collate nocase" column in a table in migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, migration, collation

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/973785/1297371 to the question: [How to set Sqlite3 to be case insensitive when string comparing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973541/how-to-set-sqlite3-to-be-case-insensitive-when-string-comparing)
tells how to create table with "COLLATE NOCASE" column.

My question is how to create such column in a rails migration?
i.e. how from

```
create table Test
(
  Text_Value  text collate nocase
);

create index Test_Text_Value_Index
  on Test (Text_Value collate nocase);
```

do:

```
create_table :tests do
  #WHAT HERE?
end
add_index #... WHAT HERE?
```

Answer (score 0):

I added new migration where I deleted and recreated the index like:

```
class AddIndexToWordVariations < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change

    remove_index :word_variations, :variation_word

    add_index :word_variations, :variation_word, :COLLATE => :NOCASE

  end

end
```

where 'word_variations' is my table

Comment: Presumably this isn't on sqlite3 (at least not back in 2013), just for people searching:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37878967/sqlite3-on-rails-create-table-using-collate-nocase

Answer (score 0):

For people searching, if 'collate' is still not available in your version of rails (you'll get "Unknown key: :COLLATE"), then you have to create the index manually:

```
execute("create index Test_Text_Value_Index on Test (Text_Value collate nocase);")
```

In your 'def up' (the 'drop_table' will drop the index as well in your 'def down')