# How can I tell if rails is using the index I manually created to do searches?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, sqlite

I needed to manually create an index for my table because rails/sqlite3 because [collation hasn't been supported yet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37880128/1795483).

So in my migration I have:

```
## This doesn't work, so we'll do it manually
#add_index :events, :name, COLLATE: :NOCASE
execute <<-SQL
  CREATE INDEX 'index_events_on_name' ON 'events' ('name' COLLATE NOCASE);
SQL
```

But evidently the index isn't being used, as I can see by trying to search for events using a name in the table, but with different case.

How can I get sqlite3 and rails to use the indexes I've created?

As an example, if I have an event with the name "Fred" and I search with:

```
Event.where("name == ?",nameVar)
```

Then I can find it when nameVar=="Fred" but not when nameVar=="fred"

Comment: Show the code that tries to use the index.

Comment: Perhaps that is the problem - the examples I've seen have shown that making an index on 'name' means that searches on 'name' will use that index.  Am I supposed to supply the index to the search somehow?  Perhaps the question could be rewritten as "how do I use an index to do a search in rails?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A COLLATE NOCASE index is used only if the search also uses this collation.

This happens when

1. the column itself is declared this way:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE events( ... name TEXT COLLATE NOCASE ...);
   ```
2. or the search explicitly uses a case-insensitive comparison:

   ```
   SELECT ... WHERE name COLLATE NOCASE = ?;
   ```
3. or you are using LIKE, which implicitly is case insensitive:

   ```
   SELECT ... WHERE name LIKE ?;
   ```

   (Look out for pattern characters. And an index for LIKE also requires the column to have text [affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity).)

Comment: You said "2.  or the search..."

Shouldn't that be "and the search"?

I.e., I have to create the table with the index and then use collate nocase in the search?

I know that 2 and 3 are possible without using a pre-created index, so I'm trying to figure out how to make sure it's using the index I've created to get the speed savings, though I suppose I could start doing some benchmarking...

Comment: Indexes and comparisons use the column's collation by default.

Comment: So then creating the index with the collation specified as nocase means that it should be using that when I search that column, no?  Because it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If the index uses the column's collation, but the search uses a different collation, then they do not match.

Comment: Unfortunately #2 doesn't work on my sqlite3 without #1 as well.

So maybe this is a sqlite3 question and has nothing to do with rails... but as I understand things, you can create a nocase index on a column that isn't necessarily set as nocase.  Is that not true?

Comment: Okay - I think it makes sense now, turns out the collation of the index doesn't matter, it's the table creation that determines collation.  If you update your answer, I'll choose it!

Comment: #2 is tested. All three require that the index is COLLATE NOCASE, too, but this happens automatically only for #1.

Comment: (Sorry that took so long to achieve understanding...  :) )