# Sqlite query optimisation needed

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm using sqlite for a small validation application. I have a simple one table database with 4 varhchar columns and one integer primary key. There are close to 1 million rows in the table. I have optimised it and done a vacuum on it.

I am using the following query to retrieve a presence count from the table. I have changed the fields and names for privacy.

```
                  SELECT 
                  count(*) as 'test'
                  FROM
                  my_table
                  WHERE
                  LOWER(surname) = LOWER('Oliver')
                  AND
                  UPPER(address_line2) = UPPER('Somewhere over the rainbow')  
                  AND
                  house_number IN ('3','4','5');
```

This query takes about 1.5-1.9 seconds to run. I have tried indexes and they make no difference really. This time may not sound bad but I have to run this test about 40,000 times on a read in csv file so as you may imagine it adds up pretty quickly. Any ideas on how to reduce the execution time. I normally develop in mssql or mysql so if there are some tricks I am missing in sqlite I would be happy to hear them.

All the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a function over an indexed column, SQLite cannot use the index, because the function may not preserve the ordering -- i.e. there can be functions such as `1>2`, but `F(1)<F(2)`. There are some ways to solve this situation, though:

1. If you want to use indexes to make your query faster, you must save
   the value in a fixed case (upper or lower) and then convert only the
   query parameter to the same case:

```sql
SELECT count(*) as 'test'
FROM my_table
WHERE surname = LOWER('Oliver')
```

1. You can use the case-insensitive LIKE operator (**I don't know how indexes are affected!**):

```sql
SELECT count(*) as 'test'
FROM my_table
WHERE surname LIKE 'Oliver';
```

1. Or you can create each column as `text collate nocase` and don't worry about case differences regarding this column anymore:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (surname text collate nocase, <... other fields here ...>);
SELECT count(*) as 'test'
FROM my_table
WHERE surname ='Oliver';
```

You can find more information about the `=` and `LIKE` operators [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html).

Comment: You my dear man are a saviour, right to the heart of the problem in only a few seconds, fair play, my hat is off to you. I will mark this as answered with you answer in a few minutes when it lets me. If I could buy you a pint now I would. Thanks again.

Comment: Ps. The execution time is now 16ms...brilliant.

Comment: To see how you can make the search case insensitive, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973541/how-to-set-sqlite3-to-be-case-insensitive-when-string-comparing.

Comment: Great information guys thanks a bunch. NOCASE all the way for me from now on.

Answer (score 1):

```
              SELECT  
              count(1) as 'test' 
              FROM 
              my_table 
              WHERE 
              surname = 'Oliver' 
              AND 
              address_line2 = 'Somewhere over the rainbow'   
              AND 
              house_number IN ('3','4','5')
              COLLATE NOCASE;
```

Comment: Very helpful to do this at the query level also thanks a million.