# SQLite query case sensitive

Tags: sql, sqlite, mono, xamarin.ios

I have a table with few columns in SQLite. I have two columns that I need to use for querying this table (code, Description). Both of these have the `COLLATE NOCASE` when creating the tables as below:

```
CREATE TABLE [AuditEvent] (
    "Code"      char(4) NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE,
    "Description"       nvarchar(255) NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE,
    "AuditEventPK"      guid NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([Code])
);
```

When I query the table using the code I get no results

```
select * from auditevent where code = 'add'    -- does not return any value

select * from auditevent where description = 'add' -- returns the right record.
```

However when I query the table using the description colomun, I get the results.

In some cases, I have to use the CODE, but it is not returning anything. Any idea??

Comment: `Code` is set to `char(4)` So it would be `'add '` with a trailing space.

Comment: Thanks Silvermind, that worked, but does that mean whenever I have char(x) I need to tailer it with spaces ??

Comment: Yes, because a `varchar` is as it's name already implies is variable in length, while `char` is not. `char` is always a fixed size. The value will be padded at the right side with spaces if you did not provide enough characters.

Comment: Thanks heaps mate, did not know about that and could find any mention to it.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appeared that I need to make the `CODE` column of type `varchar` instead of `char` as Silvermind explained. Thanks Silvermind.

Comment: It would be nice if you would add the information to your answer ;)

Comment: Also, I could not find it too for `SqLite`, but it's behaviour is common. For extra information from Oracle: [CHAR Datatype](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96524/c13datyp.htm#1961)

Comment: This kind of fixed-length field is very common in Cobol and other software from that era.