# How to use "glob" operator as case insensitive

Tags: sqlite

I am using **glob operator with "?"** wildcharater.The problem is - it is **case sensitive**.

So suppose I want to **search for "Hola"**, then below query does not work.

```
select * from tableName where columnName glob 'ho?a';
```

I can use LOWER or UPPER keywords with columnName , but then it also it fails for the text which is a combination of lower and upper case letters.

Please give your inputs.

Comment: See [this probably duplicate] [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973541/how-to-set-sqlite3-to-be-case-insensitive-when-string-comparing) - the general tool SQL has to deal with this is COLLATIONS; also, while same-casing both values ought to "work", SQLite won't be able to use indices AFAIK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GLOB` is case sensitive by design.

If you want case insensitive matching, use `LIKE`, with `_` matching a single character:

```
select * from tableName where columnName like 'ho_a';
```

Answer (score 2):

GLOB supports character classes:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE columnName GLOB '[hH][oO]?[aA]';
```

However, using LIKE would be easier, unless you actually need to use character classes in some other part of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea why the following wasn't suggested for this question:

```
select * from tableName where LOWER(columnName) glob LOWER('ho?a');
```

... in this case the second LOWER() isn't needed, I added in there in case someone stumbles accross this & forgets to ensure that's LOWERed as well

Note also that the comment added to the initial question doesn't apply - GLOB doesn't support collation directives, at least not at the current moment ...