# SQL UPPER not working

Tags: android, sql

I have a table

[image]

And try to execute this command :

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE (UPPER(title) LIKE '%КУ%' OR UPPER(description) LIKE '%КУ%')
```

In the end i want to get a row with id `2` but nothing returns to me.

But, when i change request to :

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE (UPPER(title) LIKE '%Ку%' OR UPPER(description) LIKE '%Ку%')
```

It returns row (as expected) with id `2`.

What i doing wrong? Why UPPER not worked?

Comment: You might find this post interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973541/how-to-set-sqlite3-to-be-case-insensitive-when-string-comparing

Comment: Please check the version whether it supports in your's or not

Comment: @FrankN.Stein thank you, i will read this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in Russian language :) UPPER is working only for latin alphabet. [There is question about it in ru.stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/402748/sqlite-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80-%D0%B2-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B8-where)