# do not insert case sensitive String in sqlite database

Tags: java, android, database, string, sqlite

I have a sqlite database in which So many profile names (String) are stored and i want to determine, whenever user enters a new profile name then app must have to check in the database that the same profile name is already exist or not in the case sensitivity manner .
As if there exists "Normal" then again "normal" should not be entered.

for this if there is any query or anything else ,please suggest.
Thanks for your consideration.

```
 public boolean isCaseSensitive(String rawprofile)
{
    openReadable();
    String profile=null;
    Cursor mCursor=m_sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT Profile_Name FROM Profiles WHERE profile="+rawprofile+"",null);
    if(mCursor !=null &&  mCursor.getCount()>0){
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        profile=mCursor.getString(0);
        if(profile.equals(rawprofile)){
            return  true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Any structure? Code you have tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/973785/982149

Comment: There are actually 2 approaches. 1. Insert everything in lower case and have a unique constraint on "name" column. 2. Create a unique lower-case index for the "name" column.

Comment: @SunnyRGupta i have just posted it now

Comment: yeah this question is asked earlier but i am not getting exactly how it works.....now i am using the following code but getting an exception

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: g (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT Profile_Name FROM Profiles WHERE Profile_Name COLLATE BINARY =profileName

Comment: this code i am using............... public boolean isCaseSensitive(String rawprofile)
    {
        openReadable();
        Cursor mCursor=m_sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT Profile_Name FROM Profiles WHERE Profile_Name COLLATE NOCASE ="+rawprofile+"",null);
        if(mCursor !=null &&  mCursor.getCount()>0){
         return  true;
        }
        return false;
    }