# how to make word input ignore case sensitivity of words in database

Tags: sql, sqlite, user-interface, tkinter, case-sensitive

i am developing a dictionary app with tkinter. i have some words and their meanings stored in sqlite database in which one of the word is written like "XML", "Access". Now, whenever i input a word like (xml or Xml or ACCESS or access) in entry widget and click the search button, it says "word not found". i want the word to ignore any case sensitivity. i want the meaning of a word to show up whether i type the word like "xml" or "Xml" or "ACCESS" or "access"

```
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3
from tkinter import messagebox
from ttkthemes import ThemedStyle
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os
import sys


########### DEF FOR SEARCH #######
def search(event=''):
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        data_folder=sys._MEIPASS
    else:
        data_folder=os.getcwd()

    conn = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(data_folder,'GI_DICTION4.db'))
    cur = conn.cursor()
    tex.delete(1.0, "end")
    data = v.get().swapcase()
    cur.execute("SELECT Meaning FROM Tables2 WHERE Words= ?", (data.swapcase(),))
    var = cur.fetchall()

    if var:
        tex.insert("end", var[0])  # accessing the meaning
    else:
         tex.insert("end","Word not found")



def refresh():
    entry.delete(0, "end")
    tex.delete(1.0, "end")


def fetch_data(word):
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        data_folder=sys._MEIPASS
    else:
        data_folder=os.getcwd()
    conn = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(data_folder,'GI_DICTION4.db'))
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("select Words from Tables2 where Words like ? || '%'", (word,))
    allw = cur.fetchall()
    return allw


def on_key_release(event):
    qword = event.widget.get()
    allw = fetch_data(qword)
    listbox.delete(0, tk.END)
    for w in allw:
        listbox.insert(tk.END, w[0])


def on_select(event):
    entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry.insert(0, event.widget.selection_get())


########## GUI DESIGN ##############
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the data in your table all stored in one case e.g lower case or upper case.

- If Yes, then you can convert the python string to either using `string.lower()` or `string.upper()` functions.
- You can also use COLLATE NOCASE in your SQL query to ignore case of the word.

  `SELECT Meaning FROM Tables2 WHERE words = 'XML' COLLATE NOCASE`

Check this answer - [How to set Sqlite3 to be case insensitive when string comparing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973541/how-to-set-sqlite3-to-be-case-insensitive-when-string-comparing)

Comment: In that case you can try this string.title() before passing it to the query.